# ComboBox inside a Datatemplate of listview does not work properly

Tags: c#, wpf

"ComboBox" inside a "DataTemplate" of "Listview" does not work properly.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="colTopics"  Width="100" Height="30" SelectedValue="{Binding SELECTEDTOPICProperty}" Margin="31,333,317,10">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="eyteeee"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="eyteyte"/>
</ComboBox>
```

If this 'combobox' is in 'DataTemplate' of a 'ListView', Binding of 'SelectedValue'(which is a property 'SELECTEDTOPICProperty') gives 'null' value. ComboBoxes in DataTemplate are generated dynamically.

```
<ListView  x:Name="gridTopics" BorderThickness="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TOPICSINFO}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="91,79,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="242" Width="310" BorderBrush="#FF32A3D6"  >
        <ListView.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="#FF9ADDFB"/>
        </ListView.Effect>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn  x:Name="colPageNo" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PAGENO}" Width="50" Header="Pages" />
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="colListTopics" Width="241" Header="Associated Topics" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="colTopics"  Width="100" Height="30"  SelectedValue="{Binding SELECTEDTOPICProperty}" Margin="31,333,317,10">
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="eyteeee"/>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="eyteyte"/>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

**It works fine and there is selected value in a property 'SELECTEDTOPICProperty', if 'ComboBox' is not in 'ListView'.**

```
public class TopicsInfo
{
    public TopicsInfo()
    {
        listTopics = new List<string>();
    }

    private string pageNo;

    public string PAGENO
    {
        get { return pageNo; }
        set { pageNo = value; }
    }

    private List<string> listTopics;

    public List<string> LISTTOPICS
    {
        get { return listTopics; }
        set { listTopics = value; }
    }
    private string selectedTopicString;
    public string SELECTEDTOPICProperty
    {
        get { return selectedTopicString; }
        set
        {
            selectedTopicString = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me "TOPICSINFO" and "SELECTEDTOPICProperty" detail? Is "SELECTEDTOPICProperty" is property of "TOPICSINFO"?

Comment: Thanks for reply, Code added to original question.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try to restructure your code like this if possible,

your property class,

```
public class TopicsInfo
{
    private string pageNo;

    public string PAGENO
    {
        get { return pageNo; }
        set { pageNo = value; }
    }

    private string selectedTopicString;
    public string SELECTEDTOPICProperty
    {
        get { return selectedTopicString; }
        set
        {
            selectedTopicString = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Your property to bind with ListView,

```
private ObservableCollection<TopicsInfo> topicsInfoCollection = new ObservableCollection<TopicsInfo>();

        public ObservableCollection<TopicsInfo> TopicsInfoCollection
        {
            get
            {
                return this.topicsInfoCollection;
            }

            set
            {
                this.topicsInfoCollection = value;
            }
        }
```

and your XAML code,

```
<ListView  x:Name="gridTopics" BorderThickness="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TopicsInfoCollection}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="91,79,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="242" Width="310" BorderBrush="#FF32A3D6"  >
        <ListView.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="#FF9ADDFB"/>
        </ListView.Effect>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn  x:Name="colPageNo" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PAGENO}" Width="50" Header="Pages" />
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="colListTopics" Width="241" Header="Associated Topics" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="colTopics"  Width="100" Height="30"  SelectedValue="{Binding SELECTEDTOPICProperty}" Margin="31,333,317,10">
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="eyteeee"/>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="eyteyte"/>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```